# Append multiple property values in a CosmosDB graph through Spark connector

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

We would like to append new values into a property of a vertex of a CosmosDB graph using its Spark connector.

Suppose that we have a vertex with id `'a'` that has a property `name` with value `Andrea`. If we encounter again this vertex with id `'a'` and a **different** value for the property `name` (let's say `Alice`), we would like to append `Alice` into the vertex property.
Thus, the vertex would have a property `name` with two **different** values: `Andrea` and `Alice`.

With Gremlin, it is possible to do it using `.property(list, 'name', 'Alice')`, but we didn't find a way to do it with the Spark connector. We saw the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-sql-api-spark#write-config) and we thought it was possible to do it using `spark.cosmos.write.strategy = ItemAppend`, but actually the vertex property was not updated.

*Info: for the Spark connector, we used the code at this [link](https://github.com/syedhassaanahmed/databricks-notebooks/blob/master/graph_write_cosmosdb.py).*

---

#### Example code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# starting graph
v = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Andrea", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30)
], ["id", "name", "age"]) \
.withColumn("entity", lit("person"))



def to_cosmosdb_vertices(dfVertices, labelColumn, partitionKey = ""):
  
  columns = ["id", labelColumn]
  
  if partitionKey:
    columns.append(partitionKey)
  
  columns.extend(['nvl2({x}, array(named_struct("id", uuid(), "_value", {x})), NULL) AS {x}'.format(x=x) \
                for x in dfVertices.columns if x not in columns])
 
  return dfVertices.selectExpr(*columns).withColumnRenamed(labelColumn, "label")

cosmosDbVertices = to_cosmosdb_vertices(v, "entity")



cosmosDbConfig = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" : "https://<COSMOSDB_ENDPOINT>.documents.azure.com:443/",
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey" : "<COSMOSDB_PRIMARYKEY>",
  "spark.cosmos.database" : "<DATABASE>",
  "spark.cosmos.container" : "<COLLECTION>",
  "spark.cosmos.write.strategy" : "ItemAppend"   # we tried ItemAppend here
}

cosmosDbFormat = "cosmos.oltp"

cosmosDbVertices.write.format(cosmosDbFormat).mode("append").options(**cosmosDbConfig).save()



# now we try to insert a new value for property 'name' of id 'a'
v = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", None)
], ["id", "name", "age"]) \
.withColumn("entity", lit("person"))

cosmosDbVertices = to_cosmosdb_vertices(v, "entity")

cosmosDbVertices.write.format(cosmosDbFormat).mode("append").options(**cosmosDbConfig).save()
```